# Issue with the "migrated" marker

Tags: bug, status-completed, migrated-marker

There is an issue with the [migrated] text being added to the end of a question title. If that question was migrated from another site, and closed on the site it was migrated to, it will show the [migrated] marker. Here is an example of a question with this issue: https://superuser.com/questions/269026/backup-software.

Comment: Reported on [Meta.Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86817/closed-question-has-migrated-in-the-title-on-the-target-site)

Answer (score 1):

This now checks to see if the close date is > the migration date.